# Ice under very high pressure phase transitions

Tags: water, phase, pressure

If you put a piece of ice into a very high pressure chamber and increase the pressure, I can understand how the ice turns to a water state.  But what happens after that?  Does the pressure push the water together into a crystal structure, once again, to make ice, or does the water just stay in its liquid phase?

Comment: The former. See the [phase diagram of water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_%28data_page%29#Phase_diagram). Also, chances are that you will go from one crystal structure to another directly, not touching  liquid water.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can water be liquefied or solidified just by adjusting the temperature, regardless of the pressure?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/30775/can-water-be-liquefied-or-solidified-just-by-adjusting-the-temperature-regardle) or maybe http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/9803/what-happens-to-water-under-high-pressures-without-possibility-of-escape

Comment: also http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/20009/hypothetical-what-happens-to-water-as-pressure-increases-to-infinity

Comment: Mithoron, is that spot at 0C the point where you can press water and it will melt?  And at those triple and double points can the H2O switch between phases just with the tiniest changes?

Comment: I don't understand, you can press ice to melt it and in triple points you can have equilibria of 3 phases